# Optimizing the run time of the nested for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I am just getting started with competitive programming and after writing the solution to certain problem i got the error of **RUNTIME exceeded.**

#### max( | a [ i ] - a [ j ] | + | i - j | )

Where **a** is a list of elements and **i**,**j** are index i need to get the **max()** of the above expression.

Here is a short but complete code snippet.

```
t = int(input()) # Number of test cases
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input()) #size of list
    a = list(map(int, str(input()).split())) # getting space separated input
    res = []
    for s in range(n): # These two loops are increasing the run-time
        for d in range(n):
            res.append(abs(a[s] - a[d]) + abs(s - d))
    print(max(res))
```

[Input File](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/mock-test-10/problems/197a078c9f-input-1979a41.txt.clean.txt?Signature=8qo4PWppOn3Tq2Efq2Z6dWKNiII%3D&Expires=1506630026&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ) This link may expire(Hope it works)

- 1<=t<=100
- 1<=n<=10^5
- 0<=a[i]<=10^5

Run-time on leader-board for **C language is 5sec** and that for **Python is 35sec** while this code takes **80sec**.

It is an **online judge** so independent on machine.**numpy is not available**.

Please **keep it simple** i am new to python.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why not just sort the array and take the *largest* and *smallest* elements? That way you would have maximal difference both the indices and values. The time complexity for your current method is *at least* `O(n^2)`, assuming that `append` is amortized `O(1)`. The sorting method would be `O(n log n)`.

Comment: You need to consider the indices (before sorting) as well, but yeah something along these lines is how you'd really get the time down.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for bringing sorting into picture.A question How would i know what features of a programming language or DS or ALGO to use when? Does it comes from experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `j<=i`, `|a[i]-a[j]|+|i-j| = max(a[i]-a[j]+i-j, a[j]-a[i]+i-j)`.

Thus for a given `i`, the value of `j<=i` that maximizes `|a[i]-a[j]|+|i-j|` is either the `j` that maximizes `a[j]-j` or the `j` that minimizes `a[j]+j`.

Both these values can be computed as you run along the array, giving a simple O(n) algorithm:

```
def maxdiff(xs):
    mp = mn = xs[0]
    best = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        mp = max(mp, x-i)
        mn = min(mn, x+i)
        best = max(best, x+i-mn, -x+i+mp)
    return best
```

And here's some simple testing against a naive but obviously correct algorithm:

```
def maxdiff_naive(xs):
    best = 0
    for i in xrange(len(xs)):
        for j in xrange(i+1):
            best = max(best, abs(xs[i]-xs[j]) + abs(i-j))
    return best

import random

for _ in xrange(500):
    r = [random.randrange(1000) for _ in xrange(50)]
    md1 = maxdiff(r)
    md2 = maxdiff_naive(r)
    if md1 != md2:
        print "%d != %d\n%s" % (md1, md2, r)
        exit
```

It takes a fraction of a second to run `maxdiff` on an array of size 10^5, which is significantly better than your reported leaderboard scores.

Comment: Thanks for the insight i never knew that enumerate had such power.Reduced the time from **10sec to 6sec** per test case.

Comment: There's no way a test case can take as long as 6sec if the constraints are as you described in the question. Are you using `maxdiff`, or the test code?

Comment: There were no units mentioned on the leader-board only **6** I used `maxdiff`. Also the number of testcases is large as mentioned in the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

"Competitive programming" is not about saving a few milliseconds by using a different kind of loop; it's about being smart about how you approach a problem, and *then* implementing the solution efficiently.

Still, one thing that jumps out is that you are wasting time building a list only to scan it to find the max. Your double loop can be transformed to the following (ignoring other possible improvements):

```
print(max(abs(a[s] - a[d]) + abs(s - d) for s in range(n) for d in range(n)))
```

But that's small fry. Worry about your algorithm first, and *then* turn to even obvious time-wasters like this. You can cut the number of comparisons to half, as @Brett showed you, but I would first study the problem and ask myself: Do I really need to calculate this quantity `n^2` times, or  even `0.5*n^2` times? That's how you get the times down, not by shaving off milliseconds.